# Dot symbol in tensors

Tags: tensors

First of all, this question is about **tensor analysis** and not **scalar product**.

I was reading "Tensor Analysis and Elementary Differential Geometry for Physicists and Engineers" by Nguyen-Schäfer, Hung, Schmidt, Jan-Philip ISBN 978-3-662-48495-1.

In this book, it is stated that a symbol is used in a tensor index:

> Note that in Eq. (2.70),, the dot after the lower index indicates the position of the basis of the upper index locating after the tensor T

And the equation (2.70) has the tensor $T_ { i. }^ { i }$ in it for example.

- Does this "dot" have a better name?
- Is it possible to have a more precise definition?
- Is it possible to have an unambigous example of the . symbol in action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typographical helper and not that usual in tensor notations. Usually you can see in the spacing of the indices the position, but with italics/cursive it might be ambiguous. $T{}_i{}^{jk}{}_m{}^n$ vs. roman $\mathrm{T{}_i{}^{jk}{}_m{}^n}$. It might also help to have a denser source for the text and take less space in the printed text, $T^{.jk.n}_{i..m}$

Comment: Are you sure it's that? The book does seem to talk about it having a real meaning about the base or something? No?

Comment: The meaning comes from the position, upper indices for contravariant coordinates, lower indices for covariant coordinates, in my example $T$ would be in $V\otimes V^*\otimes V^*\otimes V\otimes V^*$ (each factor also could be a different vector space). The punctuation only serves to fix the order of the factor spaces.

Comment: can you provide an example, please?

Comment: An example of what? That you could write the above mentioned tensor also as $T^{.jk.n}_{i..m}$? Is that conform with the use in the book?

Comment: Wait I think I misread, so you say that $T_ { k. }^ { l }$ means that the first index is the upper index $k$ , then the second $l$ ?

Comment: Ok, seems the notation also omits leading dots. What you wrote is $T{}_k{}^l$, first a lower $k$ then an upper $l$, making this $T$ an element of $Hom(V^*)\simeq V^*\otimes V$.

Comment: Oh ok thank you